# Prove the logarithmic spiral intersects all radius vectors at the same angle

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that the logarithmic , the equation of which is $r = Ce^{k\theta}$, intersects all radius vectors at the same angle.

I'm assuming this relates to the **radius-tangent angle** that I will define as $\psi$. If i denote the respective radius-tangent angles by $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, then:

$$\alpha = \psi_1 - \psi_2$$

And

$$\tan\alpha = \frac{\tan\psi_1-\tan\psi_2}{1 + \tan\psi_1\tan\psi_2}$$

So I thought of rearranging the equation of $r$ to find $\theta$, such that $\frac{ln(r)}{k}+C = \theta$, though ?I'm not sure how to proceed from here and would really be grateful for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way: Apply a similarity transform $r\mapsto e^\alpha r$, $\theta\mapsto\theta+\alpha/k$.

Slower way: Note that the angle between tangent and radial vector is $\cot^{-1}(\frac1r\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta})$ since $\mathbf{e}_r,\frac1r\mathbf{e}_\theta$ is an orthonormal frame.